# libMobileGestalt.dylib crashed when Hooking MGCopyAnswer for ARM64

Tags: hook, jailbreak

When I try to hook MGCopyAnswer, I get a crash. I'm trying this on a jailbroken iPhone 5s in iOS 8.3, arm64 binaries.

```
#import <substrate.h>

extern "C" CFTypeRef MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef);
MSHook(CFTypeRef, MGCopyAnswer, CFStringRef key)
{
  return _MGCopyAnswer(key);
}

%ctor
{
  NSString *appID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
  if ( appID && [appID isEqualToString:@"com.test.test"])   {
    MSHookFunction(MGCopyAnswer, MSHake(MGCopyAnswer));
  }
}
```

Makefile:

```
ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
TARGET = iphone:latest:8.0
test2_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = test2
test2_FILES = Tweak.xm
test2_LIBRARIES = MobileGestalt

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
  install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Crash log:

```
Version: 1.44 (1.4)
Code Type: ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-04-25 01:09:31.810 +0800
Launch Time:         2016-04-25 01:09:31.564 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000068fe68
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libMobileGestalt.dylib          0x0000000195af7e84 0x195af4000 + 16004
1   libMobileGestalt.dylib          0x0000000195af82bc MGGetBoolAnswer + 32
2   AppSupport                      0x000000018b020594 __CPIsInternalDevice_block_invoke + 16
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c99950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c9a828 dispatch_once_f + 92
5   AppSupport                      0x000000018b02057c CPIsInternalDevice + 60
6   UIKit                           0x0000000189b58750 ___UIApplicationUsesAlternateUI_block_invoke + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c99950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c9a828 dispatch_once_f + 92
9   UIKit                           0x0000000189923750 UIApplicationInitialize + 1872
10  UIKit                           0x0000000189922b1c UIApplicationMain + 320

MGCopyAnswer:
->  0x193a7fe84 <+0>:  .long  0x002d7c28                ; unknown opcode
    0x193a7fe88 <+4>:  .long  0x00000001                ; unknown opcode
    0x193a7fe8c <+8>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #32]
    0x193a7fe90 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #48]
    0x193a7fe94 <+16>: add    x29, sp, #48
    0x193a7fe98 <+20>: sub    sp, sp, #48
    0x193a7fe9c <+24>: mov    x19, x1
    0x193a7fea0 <+28>: mov    x22, x0
    0x193a7fea4 <+32>: movz   w0, #0
    0x193a7fea8 <+36>: bl     0x193a7f564               ; ___lldb_unnamed_function54$$libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x193a7feac <+40>: orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
    0x193a7feb0 <+44>: mov    x0, x22
    0x193a7feb4 <+48>: bl     0x193a7f5fc               ; ___lldb_unnamed_function56$$libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x193a7feb8 <+52>: mov    x21, x0
    0x193a7febc <+56>: movz   w20, #0
    0x193a7fec0 <+60>: cbz    x21, 0x193a7fefc          ; <+120>
    0x193a7fec4 <+64>: ldr    w20, [x21, #148]
    0x193a7fec8 <+68>: mov    x0, x21
orig_MGCopyAnswer
    0x104234000: movz   x1, #0
    0x104234004: stp    x24, x23, [sp, #-64]!
    0x104234008: stp    x22, x21, [sp, #16]
    0x10423400c: ldr    x16, #8
    0x104234010: br     x16
    0x104234014: .long  0x93a7fe8c                
    0x104234018: .long  0x00000001                ; unknown opcode
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

**You cannot hook `MGCopyAnswer` directly because it is too short.**

When CydiaSubstrate hooks a C function, it sorts of overwrites an assembly version of `goto your_function;` at the beginning of the original function. This "goto" in ARM64 is 16 bytes in size, which means if the original function is too short (< 16 bytes), CydiaSubstrate can spill over and corrupt the neighboring functions.

This is exactly why the problem of `MGCopyAnswer`. The implementation of `MGCopyAnswer` is basically (on 9.3.2 arm64):

```
01 00 80 d2        movz x1, #0
01 00 00 14        b    MGCopyAnswer_internal
```

which is just 8 bytes (< 16 bytes) in size. So CydiaSubstrate will corrupt the 8 bytes after the end of `MGCopyAnswer`.

Unfortunately, `MGCopyAnswer_internal` is right after `MGCopyAnswer`, and even worse this function and is called by `MGGetBoolAnswer` as well. Since `MGCopyAnswer_internal` is corrupt, you get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION crash inside libMobileGestalt.

**A good news for `MGCopyAnswer` is that, you could just hook `MGCopyAnswer_internal`!** This has an additional benefit that many related functions like `MGGetBoolAnswer`, `MGCopyAnswerWithError`, `MGCopyMultipleAnswers` etc. can respond to your change as well. The bad thing is that `MGCopyAnswer_internal` is completely internal, and there is no symbols pointing to it. We could rely on the fact that `MGCopyAnswer_internal` is exactly 8 bytes after `MGCopyAnswer` on ARM64, and develop this ugly hack:

```
static CFPropertyListRef (*orig_MGCopyAnswer_internal)(CFStringRef prop, uint32_t* outTypeCode);
CFPropertyListRef new_MGCopyAnswer_internal(CFStringRef prop, uint32_t* outTypeCode) {
    return orig_MGCopyAnswer_internal(prop, outTypeCode);
}

extern "C" MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef prop);

static CFPropertyListRef (*orig_MGCopyAnswer)(CFStringRef prop);
CFPropertyListRef new_MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef prop) {
    return orig_MGCopyAnswer(prop);
}

%ctor {
    uint8_t MGCopyAnswer_arm64_impl[8] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xd2, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14};
    const uint8_t* MGCopyAnswer_ptr = (const uint8_t*) MGCopyAnswer;
    if (memcmp(MGCopyAnswer_ptr, MGCopyAnswer_arm64_impl, 8) == 0) {
        MSHookFunction(MGCopyAnswer_ptr + 8, (void*)new_MGCopyAnswer_internal, (void**)&orig_MGCopyAnswer_internal);
    } else {
        MSHookFunction(MGCopyAnswer_ptr, (void*)new_MGCopyAnswer, (void**)&orig_MGCopyAnswer);
    }
}
```

(This only checks for arm64 on 9.3.2. Other platforms may crash in different ways, and have different assembly code, so you may need to add additional conditions into enter the hook-`MGCopyAnswer_internal` branch. YMMV!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#import <substrate.h>

static CFTypeRef (*orig_MGCopyAnswer)(CFStringRef str);
CFTypeRef new_MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef str)
{
    return orig_MGCopyAnswer(str);
}

%ctor
{
  NSString *appID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
  if ( appID && [appID isEqualToString:@"com.test.test"]) {
    void * MGCopyAnswerFn = MSFindSymbol(NULL, "_MGCopyAnswer");
    MSHookFunction(MGCopyAnswerFn, (void *) new_MGCopyAnswer, (void **)& orig_MGCopyAnswer);
  }
}
```